# Why the contents of the second 'if' never executed?

Tags: pine-script

I think it needs to work but does not. Please help me find out why?
Thank you

```
//@version=5
strategy("Week High Low - Buy Strategy")

thisyear = year(timenow)
thisweek = weekofyear(timenow)
lastweekhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
lastweeklow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
halfline = (lastweekhigh + lastweeklow) / 2

buysignal = false
if close < halfline and close > lastweeklow
    i = 1
    while year[i] == thisyear and weekofyear[i] == thisweek
        if close[i] > lastweekhigh
            buysignal := true
            break
        i += 1

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1, when = buysignal)
```

Answer (score 0):

if close < halfline and close > lastweeklow , use "or" except of using "and" , faced same error couple of weeks==

Comment: Sometimes this happens in real world (code), but why is the variable (buysignal) never gets true in this code snippet?